# restore IAP based on user google play/amazon store account

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

My app contains IAP and I want users to be able to install the app on a new device and recover those purchases. I don't have any type of login requirement so there is no backend to access to check for credentials and then restore IAP.

I know that on iOS it is possible to restore IAP simply by calling a specific function (`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`).

Is there something similar in google play and amazon? If not, how could I restore IAP?

Comment: There is, [take a look at official document here.](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#QueryPurchases)

Comment: Awesome! And for amazon?

Comment: For Amazon-  https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/implementing-iap-2.0#7.%20Retrieving%20Purchase%20History%20for%20the%20Current%20User

Comment: Put them together into an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From google play' official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#QueryPurchases): you need to call `queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener)` method and handle the data in `QueryInventoryFinishedListener`.

[From Amazon's documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/implementing-iap-2.0#7.%20Retrieving%20Purchase%20History%20for%20the%20Current%20User): you need to call `PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates()` method for retrieving users purchase history